# Appium Inspector Failed to create a session?

Tags: appium, appium-android, inspector

Appium Automations:

Appium Inspector facing Error -Failed to create session. The requested resource could not be found, or a request was received using an HTTP method that is not supported by the mapped resource

I tried given with Remote path -/wd/hub -The issue not resolved